# EKS Pods with ephemeral-storage constantly evicted

Tags: kubernetes, request, limits, kubectl, eks

I'm working on EKS v1.20.11-eks-f17b81 and I'm facing an issue with a Java container Alpine based. Basically my deployment have the limits of ephemeral-storage for the request's and also the limit's like this.

```
- containerPort: 8080
  protocol: TCP
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 2048m
    ephemeral-storage: 1300Mi
    memory: 4096M
  requests:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 1024M
    ephemeral-storage: 1000Mi
```

The pods after a few hours all of them, will be on Evicted state, and I'm not able to understand why, if I take a look at the /var/lib folder on the nodes there's plenty of space, also if I go to some pod with **kubectl exec -ti POD -- sh** and I do something like du -sch / I never found more than 300MB used, what can be happening ?.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Either don't use `ephemeral-storage` limits at all or use them on all containers in the pod.

---

I guess you don't have `ephemeral-storage` limits set for **all containers** in that particular pod. Eviction manager sums all limits of containers and sets it as upper limit **on pod level**.

This is actual [code snippet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.20.11/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L456-L482):

```go
func (m *managerImpl) localStorageEviction(pods []*v1.Pod, statsFunc statsFunc) []*v1.Pod {
    evicted := []*v1.Pod{}
    for _, pod := range pods {
        podStats, ok := statsFunc(pod)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }

        if m.emptyDirLimitEviction(podStats, pod) {
            evicted = append(evicted, pod)
            continue
        }

        if m.podEphemeralStorageLimitEviction(podStats, pod) {
            evicted = append(evicted, pod)
            continue
        }

        if m.containerEphemeralStorageLimitEviction(podStats, pod) {
            evicted = append(evicted, pod)
        }
    }

    return evicted
}
```

As you can see both `podEphemeralStorageLimitEviction` and `containerEphemeralStorageLimitEviction` are used for eviction. As of writing I don't understand "why" both are used (and not just container one).